# Does character set and collation affects query performance in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, query-performance

I have been working on a database with large and expanding database in MariaDB. The database is accessed by a PHP application.

I set the DB character set and collation to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci

But not all my tables has text (varchar, text etc.) columns. Some tables holds only relations, thus all columns are number types (int, bigint etc) or date/time etc. additionally but not text types.

In tables, where I only keep numbers, do I need to keep the unicode multi-byte character set/collation or I can select something else?

Most importantly does this **affect the query performance**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though your table has a collation and character set, the columns with numeric values do not need any collation and character set definition. Hence, it's irrelevant to consider selecting anything like that. You can create a table like below without defining collation for numeric columns:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    c0 INT NOT NULL,
    c1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET latin1
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci;
```

Yes, it does affect query performance. Please know that a character set is essentially a single character being saved with a different number of bytes. If there are only English alphabets, usually Latin is the best character set. Also, based on your MySQL version, different character sets give different performance. Please refer to this article as well. This might help.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/27/charset-and-collation-settings-impact-on-mysql-performance/

Comment: Thanks. I understand. But would you take some time to tell me if character set and collation affects query performance? For example, if a table only contains English alphabets then which character set and collation should I be using instead of utf8mb4 and how it helps query performance (if any)?

Comment: Yes, it does affect query performance. Please know that a character set is essentially a single character being saved with a different number of bytes. If there are only English alphabets, usually Latin is the best character set.  Also, based on your mysql version, different character sets give different performance. Please refer to this article as well. This might help. https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/27/charset-and-collation-settings-impact-on-mysql-performance/

Comment: You can write the above comment as answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The things that affect performance, approximately *in order*:

- Poor indexing
- Poor formulation of queries
- Disk I/O
- The number rows that need to be read to satisfy a query
- At the bottom of this list:  expressions, functions, character set, collations, etc.

That is, *Use the character sets and collations you need; don't worry about performance*.

Comment: But doesn't the character set has an impact on indexing? Your index for the same amount of characters would occupy much more storage in utf8mb4 vs latin1. So I would expect and Index lookup to perform worse for utf8mb4 as you have to process more data, especially if the index cannot fit in memory.

Comment: @codewandler - Yes, that is in my last bullet item.  The size of an INDEX is not different except that accented letters in latin1 take 1 byte, but 2 bytes in utf8 or utf8mb4.